# Use different timeframes for different functions

Tags: pine-script

Hey so i'm trying to define different timeframes for different functions say for example this

```
[_, _, histo] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9), barmerge.gaps_on, barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

but the histo remains n/a while the script runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have `barmerge.gaps_on`so it does not merge the requested data automatically with the main series data. Either remove that or use `barmerge.gaps_off`.

Please read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html#barmerge-gaps-and-lookahead) for more information.